# How could I link the Boost (not in usr/include) in CMakeList.txt using find_package

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Now, I need to use `" find_package(Boost 1.62.0 COMPONENTS program_options serialization system filesystem thread REQUIRED)"` to include some libs into my program, but my boost library is installed in other directory, not in the defualt directory**(usr/include..)**. Now it occurs the following errors:

```
 CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1138 (message):  
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.  
  Boost version: 1.41.0  
  Boost include path: /usr/includ  
  Detected version of Boost is too old.    
  Requested version was 1.62 (or
  newer).
```

I give out some contents of my CMakelist.txt:

```
SET(BOOST_DIR /home/mingjli/folder_Mingjie/Software/boost_1.62.0/include/boost)
SET(BOOST_LIB /home/mingjli/folder_Mingjie/Software/boost_1.62.0/lib)  
INCLUDE (${Source_Path}/IndexerLauncher.cmake NO_POLICY_SCOPE)  
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${BOOST_DIR})  
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${BOOST_LIB})  
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Source_Path})  
ADD_EXECUTABLE (indexer_launcher ${IndexerLauncher})  
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (indexer_launcher nearest_search_lib)  
target_link_libraries( indexer_launcher ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Boost version: 1.41.0  
                 ^^
```

This means, that you have boost version 1.41.0 installed, but you are requesting 1.62.0. You can update boost or change minimal boost version requirements:

```
find_package(Boost 1.41.0 COMPONENTS program_options serialization system filesystem thread REQUIRED)
                     ^^
```

There is nothing really special you should have in your CMakeLists.txt to include Boost. Here is a sample that works for me:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED filesystem system)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(mytarget ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

**UPDATE:**
If you can't update your system boost version, you can install boost into your home folder:

1. download boost sources from www.boost.org
2. compile and install new boost into **your home directory**:

   `b2 toolset=gcc install --prefix=/home/user/boost`

After boost is compiled - you can use it from /home/user/boost:

```
cmake .. -DBOOST_ROOT=/home/user/boost
```

Comment: Hi, I know what you mean. But I need the boost 1.62, not the boost 1.41. Unfortunately, I don't have the permission to update the boost 1.41 to 1.62, this is an issue. @Evgeniy

Comment: @MingjieLi, you can install new boost into your home folder. Check answer updates

Comment: Hi,@Evgeniy, thank you very much, is OK now. However, it occurs new problem,  'missing_parameter' is not a member of 'boost::program_options::invalid_syntax'. I have checked that invalid_syntax really contains the the member "missing_parameter",

Comment: @MingjieLi, your include_directories code may be incorrect. use include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}) instead of INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${BOOST_DIR}) . You can also display include directories by message() and check if they are correct

Comment: This problem occurs before, I previously think that this problem is due to the boost 1.41 as in this version, the invalid_syntax class doesn't have the member of missing_parameter. But, the version 1.62 has that member, so I don't know why, do you have any ideas about this issue.  Thank you !